# spring cloud contract gerenate producer classes test

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

In producer side, I need to skip stubs generation (so I need only to generate classes tests). for that Change the maven plugin as follow:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<version>3.0.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>convert</goal>
            <!--goal>generateStubs</goal-->
            <goal>generateTests</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

But with this config, stubs still generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're providing goals yourself do not set `<extensions>true</extensions>`